# New installation (and user) unable to get Broadcom adapter to work

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

Having trouble using the help section to get my Broadcom adapter to work. It is not helped by the fact that I don't have another internet connection. I found this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Broadcom_BCM4311_rev_01_%28ndiswrapper%29
and made it through the first few steps but totally hit a wall. Can anyone offer advice on how to get the correct driver? I do have access to a Windows PC

["screenshot"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JF7F.jpg)